# Why ScrollViewer fired PointerCaptureLost when starting scroll?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

In my Windows Store App (c#, xaml) I have `ScrollViewer`, when I zoom in it and trying to scroll - the `ScrollViewer` fired event `PointerCaptureLost` and I can't handle any pointers events anymore.
Why it happens, and how I can handle pointers events (for example `PointerMoved`) during scroll `ScrollViewer`?

Comment: you have to handle it using e.Handle=true

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it may not be possible without some serious hacks.

> *What's happening is that whenever there is "a touch event that causes the FlipView to animate ", the thing that is causing that animation is the ScrollViewer built into the FlipView, used for flipping.   The scrollviewer takes away pointer input until the panning has completed and it cannot be taken back.   This is a feature called DirectManipulation which is now processing input on a separate thread to give the smoothest possible panning handling.  (Pointer* events fire in the UI Thread)*

in http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/1e6732d3-0457-4ddc-b762-963ab974491c/pointerreleased-and-flipview