# Touch on screen while ScrollViewer.ChangeView is active breaks app UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, uwp, scrollview

I have windows phone 10 (C# UWP) app and I am using scrollviewer in listview to show slide of images. On view changed event for scrollviewer I check which image container is more visible for user and use ChangeView method to move that image to be the only one seen on display. This all works well, but if I press and hold touch screen while ChangeView is active, images resize and I get an error "this object has been sealed, so this change is no longer allowed" which I can't catch.

XAML:
(Note, CurrentSizeConverter just gives visible page bounds based on parameter)

```
<Page.Resources>             
    <DataTemplate x:Key="dtPhotoView">
        <Grid x:Name="grPhotoView" Width="{Binding Id, Converter={StaticResource CurrentSizeConverter}, ConverterParameter=Width}" Height="{Binding Id, Converter={StaticResource CurrentSizeConverter}, ConverterParameter=Height}">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Image x:Name="imgFullSize" Source="{Binding ImageSource}" Stretch="Fill" Grid.RowSpan="2"/>
            <Grid Grid.Row="1" x:Name="grDeleteFullImage" Background="#66000000">
                <Button x:Name="btnDeletePhoto" Style="{StaticResource btnActionCommandButtonStyle}" Tag="{Binding Id}" Canvas.ZIndex="10" Margin="0" Click="btnDeletePhoto_Click" Background="#66000000" Padding="10">
                    <Button.Foreground>
                        <ImageBrush Stretch="Uniform" ImageSource="Assets/delete_icon.png"/>
                    </Button.Foreground>
                </Button>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</Page.Resources>

<Grid>
    <ListView HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Visibility="Collapsed" SelectionMode="None" IsItemClickEnabled="False" x:Name="lvPhotoView" Grid.Row="0" DataContext="{Binding}" Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource dtPhotoView}" ScrollViewer.ZoomMode="Disabled"  ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Enabled" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Disabled" PointerEntered="lvPhotoView_PointerEntered">
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
                <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2" />
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <ItemsStackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemsPanel>
    </ListView> .........
```

Private variables:

```
private static bool _imagesShowing = false;
private ScrollViewer _imagesViewer;
```

Event handling:

```
private void lvPhotoView_PointerEntered(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.Input.PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (!_imagesShowing)
        {
            _imagesShowing = true;

            if (_imagesViewer == null)
            {
                _imagesViewer = GetScrollViewer(lvPhotoView);
            }

            if (_imagesViewer != null)
            {
                _imagesViewer.ViewChanged += ImagesScrollViewer_OnViewChanged;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return;
    }
}

public static ScrollViewer GetScrollViewer(DependencyObject depObj)
{
    try
    {
        if (depObj is ScrollViewer)
        {
            return depObj as ScrollViewer;
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(depObj); i++)
        {
            var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(depObj, i);

            var result = GetScrollViewer(child);
            if (result != null)
            {
                return result;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
    catch
    {
        return null;
    }
}

private async void ImagesScrollViewer_OnViewChanged(object sender, ScrollViewerViewChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (!e.IsIntermediate)
    {
        var isDone = false;
        try
        {
            _imagesViewer.ViewChanged -= ImagesScrollViewer_OnViewChanged;
            _imagesViewer.HorizontalScrollMode = ScrollMode.Disabled;
            _imagesViewer.IsScrollInertiaEnabled = false;

            for (var i = 0; i < lvPhotoView.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                var item = lvPhotoView.Items[i];
                var itemContainer = lvPhotoView.ContainerFromItem(item) as ListViewItem;

                double firstVisValue;

                var isVisible = itemContainer.IsVisibileToUserHorizontal(sender as ScrollViewer, out firstVisValue);

                if (isVisible && lvPhotoView.Items.Count - 1 > i)
                {
                    var nextItem = lvPhotoView.Items[i + 1];
                    var secondItemContainer = lvPhotoView.ContainerFromItem(nextItem) as ListViewItem;

                    double secondVisValue;

                    var isNextVisible = secondItemContainer.IsVisibileToUserHorizontal(sender as ScrollViewer, out secondVisValue);

                    if (isNextVisible)
                    {

                        _imagesViewer.ScrollToElement(firstVisValue < secondVisValue ? secondItemContainer : itemContainer);
                    }

                    await Task.Delay(800);
                    _imagesViewer.HorizontalScrollMode = ScrollMode.Enabled;
                    _imagesViewer.IsScrollInertiaEnabled = true;
                    _imagesShowing = false;
                    isDone = true;
                }
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            if (!isDone)
            {
                await Task.Delay(500);
                _imagesViewer.HorizontalScrollMode = ScrollMode.Auto;
                _imagesViewer.IsScrollInertiaEnabled = true;
                _imagesShowing = false;
            }
        }
    }
}

public static bool IsVisibileToUserHorizontal(this FrameworkElement element, FrameworkElement container, out double visValue)
{
    visValue = 0;

    if (element == null || container == null)
    {
        return false;
    }

    if (element.Visibility != Visibility.Visible)
    {
        return false;
    }

    var elementBounds = element.TransformToVisual(container).TransformBounds(new Rect(0.0, 0.0, element.ActualWidth, element.ActualHeight));
    var containerBounds = new Rect(0.0, 0.0, container.ActualWidth, container.ActualHeight);

    if (elementBounds.Left >= containerBounds.Left && elementBounds.Left < containerBounds.Right)
    {
        visValue = containerBounds.Right - elementBounds.Left;
        return true;
    }

    if (elementBounds.Right >= containerBounds.Left && elementBounds.Right < containerBounds.Right)
    {
        visValue = elementBounds.Right - containerBounds.Left;
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

public static void ScrollToElement(this ScrollViewer scrollViewer, UIElement element, bool isHorizontalScrolling = true, bool smoothScrolling = true, float? zoomFactor = null)
{
    var transform = element.TransformToVisual((UIElement)scrollViewer.Content);
    var position = transform.TransformPoint(new Point(0, 0));

    if (isHorizontalScrolling)
    {
        scrollViewer.ChangeView(position.X, null, zoomFactor, !smoothScrolling);
    }
    else
    {
        scrollViewer.ChangeView(null, position.Y, zoomFactor, !smoothScrolling);
    }
}
```

Finally, bind any observable collection list with xaml binding properties where ImageSource property is image StorageFile (in my case they are all .jpg) to list view.

Essentially when smoothScrolling is true, scrolling is in progress and I tap and hold item, items resize and I can move them around while holding, and when I let go app brakes with unhandled exception from above.

Any ideas?

Comment: There is no enough code to reproduce your issue.  Please reference [ask] to provide a reproduced project. At least where and how you call `ScrollToElement` method.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I updated code snippets, now everything should be reproducible. So, when you scroll and let go ScrollToElement is called and scrollview automatically scrolls to image that is more visible to the user. While this automatic scroll is going, tap to screen and swipe up/down and the issue will happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be interfering with DirectManipulation, hence the exception while scrolling.

*What's happening is that whenever there is "a touch event that causes the FlipView to animate ", the thing that is causing that animation is the ScrollViewer built into the FlipView, used for flipping. The scrollviewer takes away pointer input until the panning has completed and it cannot be taken back. This is a feature called DirectManipulation which is now processing input on a separate thread to give the smoothest possible panning handling. (Pointer events fire in the UI Thread)*
in http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/1e6732d3-0457-4ddc-b762-963ab974491c/pointerreleased-and-flipview

Same issue encountered here: [Why ScrollViewer fired PointerCaptureLost when starting scroll?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24201220/why-scrollviewer-fired-pointercapturelost-when-starting-scroll/25209208#25209208)

Comment: I am not having exception while scrolling. Nor am I using FlipView. I am programmatically starting animation of ScrollViewer built into the ListView and then, while animation is in progress, when I tuch and move up/down (not left/right) I get exception.

Comment: Yes, the example I gave was from FlipView, but internally it's a ScrollViewer, same as your case. Point is, ScrollViewer uses direct manipulation which is a hardware accelerated, exclusive pipeline. As soon as you try to fumble with data involved in the pipeline, you'll always get exceptions.

Comment: I see, this does give me better understanding of what causes the issue and where to look. Do you have any good idea for some workaround (not to allow user to tap ListView while ScrollView is holding the pointer, something like that)?

Comment: You should definitely manage when the user interactions are allowed. Something as simple as unsubscribing the touch event while busy and resubscribing before returning.